# Develop WP8 using VS Community 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, vs-community-edition

Is there any way to develop wp8 app using Visual Studio Community 2013 edition? I've installed wp8 sdk, but still I can't see wp8 template.

Comment: Have you installed "Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later"? (the latest is [Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44921))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File > New Project > Visual C# > Windows Store Apps > Windows Phone Applications > Blank App(Silverlight Application for Windows Phone)

insert the name of the project and click ok!

Visual studio will prompt you to choose between 8.0 or 8.1!

Choose 8.0, done! ;)